# Tools for symbolic calculations of quantum transport using the Keldysh NEGF formalism

Tags: software-recommendations, mathematical-modeling, quantum-mechanics, greens-functions

I am looking for tools for symbolic calculation of quantum transport or quantum mechanics that involves Keldysh NEGF (non-equilibrium Green's function) formalism.  The closest tool I heard/seen is `symGF.m` for Mathematica but I could not find the library/file for it.   Have anyone seen this file or equivalent tools?

Comment: For SymGF, you might want to try contacting the authors. While Zimin Feng appears to have left physics after graduation, Prof. [Hong Guo](http://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~guo/) is still at McGill.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our new community and thank you for contributing your question here! We hope to see much more of you in the future! I totally agree that you should probably try to ask Hong Guo for the file. I don't expect there to be dozens and dozens of software for this niche type of calculation, so whatever is out there (e.g. symGF.m) might be one of the only tools available and I think you should try your best to get your hands on it by contacting the authors and people who may know them (I personally don't)! Also, what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Thank you @NikeDattani , I have done some calculations of quantum transport by NEGF method using Keldysh formalism before manually and I found it to be very tricky and tedious.   I will probably will have to do again in some future and I wondered if I could automate in Mathematica at least.  While researching online, I found work by Feng who developed symGF.m for this type of method.   I wanted to learn from it and maybe improve on it instead of reinventing the wheel from scratch.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned (the OP has not returned since asking the question). It can be reopened if someone would like to provide an answer.